# Vectorization of class method

Tags: c++, vectorization, icc

I have a class called **Grid** that contains a method that I want to vectorize, called **countNeighbors**.

Inside the **main** program, I have declered and defined the Grid class with all its components, vectorizing properly the code of the countNeighbors method: using the **elemental function notation**.

The main function contains a **loop, that calls at each step the countNeighbors method**, vectorized properly using the **array notation**.

I have compiled as following:

```
icpc -std=c++11 -DNO_DEFAULT_MAPPING -O3 -finline-functions -DNDEBUG -o main main.cpp
```

When I compile, the loop is **correctly vectorized**.

Instead, if I move the code of the Grid class in two different files: *Grid.hpp* and *Grid.cpp*, when I compile I obtain that:

1. In *Grid.o* the countNeighbors function is **correctly vectorized**
2. In the main, the **loop is not vectorized**, reporting the following diagnostic:

   ```
   LOOP BEGIN at main.cpp(48,52)
       remark #15382: vectorization support: call to function Grid::countNeighbors(const Grid *, size_t, int) const cannot be vectorized   [ main.cpp(48,31) ]
       remark #15344: loop was not vectorized: vector dependence prevents vectorization
   LOOP END
   ```

I have tried to add the **#pragma ivdep** o **#pragma vector always** directives above the main loop, and I have tried to add the **option -ipo**, but the result remains the same.

**What can I do in order to vectorize my code ?**

#### Solved:

I am really sorry, I just realized that I was not putting the **ipo** flag while creating the object file. Now, compiling as following I obtain the correct result:

```
icpc -std=c++11 -DNO_DEFAULT_MAPPING -O3 -finline-functions -DNDEBUG -ipo -I . -c grid.cpp grid.hpp -o grid.o
icpc -std=c++11 -DNO_DEFAULT_MAPPING -O3 -finline-functions -DNDEBUG -ipo  -I . -o main main.cpp grid.o
```

Comment: Someone might have a better guess if you showed the source code of the loop.

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly inferred what you didn't quite say, you have a loop containing a call to a trivial function.  When that trivial function definition is available (in the same compilation unit) it is inlined and as a result of the function being inlined the loop is vectorized.  But when the function definition is not in the same compilation unit, it isn't vectorized.

All that should be what you would expect.  So put the definition in Grid.hpp not in Grid.cpp

`-ipo` **might** get around the need to have the definition in the same compilation unit.  But that isn't working that way for you (and never did for me) so it doesn't seem wise to depend on that.